# Undefined index: leveluser php in session?

Tags: php

why user-level posts Undefined index

what's wrong my code?

```
<?php

            if ($_SESSION['leveluser'] == 'supplier')
            {
                include "menu_sup.php";
            }
            else if($_SESSION['leveluser'] == 'distributor')
            {
                include "menu_dis.php";
            }
            else{


        ?>
```

Notice: Undefined index: leveluser in C:\xampp\htdocs\apotikphp\menu.php on line 4

Comment: Did you [`session_start()`](http://us1.php.net/session_start)?

Comment: What makes you believe that `$_SESSION` should have an entry at index `leveluser`? BTW, this is not a rhetorical question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As error say $_SESSION['leveluser'] is not defined or initialize.

better to use like this:

```
        if (isset($_SESSION['leveluser']) && $_SESSION['leveluser'] == 'supplier')
        {
            include "menu_sup.php";
        }
        else if(isset($_SESSION['leveluser']) && $_SESSION['leveluser'] == 'distributor')
        {
            include "menu_dis.php";
        }
        else{
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `session_start()` , and `$_SESSION['leveluser']` is not set. That is the reason you got the **notice**. Make sure you have assigned the value to the  `$_SESSION['leveluser']`.

when the *Notice: Undefined index* occurs - Use `isset()` function  — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

```
 <?php    
        session_start();   

       if ($_SESSION['leveluser'] == 'supplier')
       {
        include "menu_sup.php";
       }
       else if($_SESSION['leveluser'] == 'distributor')
       {
        include "menu_dis.php";
       }
       else{

       }  

 ?>
```

Ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\apotikphp\menu.php on line 3